# Chaining result with "WITH" doesn't work when the subsequent query doesn't have matched result in Neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example, I created two linked nodes:

```
create (a:ACTOR {id: "a1", name: "bruce wellis"})
create (m:MOVIE {id: "m1", title: "die hardest"})
create (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
```

**1.** From this cypher query:

```
match (a:ACTOR {id: "a1"})
with a
optional match (m:MOVIE {id: "m1"})
set m += {
    title: "die easier"
}
return a;
```

I can have result:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| a                                       |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Node[1000]{name:"bruce wellis",id:"a1"} |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row
Properties set: 1
```

The query successfully returned the actor node.

**2. (UPDATED)** But if you make the match MOVIE subquery failed:

```
match (a:ACTOR {id: "a1"})
with a
optional match (m:MOVIE {id: "mm"})
set m += {
    title: "die easier"
}
return a;
```

I got error:

```
CypherTypeException: Expected m to be a node or a relationship, but it was :`null`.
```

How to make the second query returning matched actor result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `MATCH` that fails to match anything will always return no rows.

So, in #2, since the second `MATCH` failed, it returns no rows.

You could use `OPTIONAL MATCH` in place of the second `MATCH`, and you should see results.

[EDITED]
For the Updated question, this (somewhat ugly) workaround should work:

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR {id: "a1"})
WITH a
OPTIONAL MATCH (m:MOVIE {id: "mm"})
WITH a, COLLECT(m) AS cm
FOREACH(m IN cm | SET m += {title: "die easier"})
RETURN a;
```

Comment: Hi, please see the updated question. It doesn't work if I update the movie node with set.

Comment: Your `SET` clause fails if `m` is NULL. Use this clause instead: `SET m.title = "die easier"`. It does nothing (and does not cause an error) if `m` is NULL.

Comment: But if there are a lot of properties, it would be convenient to use direct node set (`SET m += { params }`) especially if I made the call from application using [cypher parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html). Is there a solution for this?

Comment: See my updated answer. The `FOREACH` clause will skip over `NULL` items in `cm`.